# Android studio with experimental gradle 0.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to setup a basic ndk build with the latest version of android studio at this moment. Trying to follow [this tutorial](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental)

[image]

This is my **gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Thu Sep 17 14:22:34 CST 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip
```

This is the project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my module's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "me.blubee.testnative_exp"
            minSdkVersion = 10
            targetSdkVersion = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }

        buildConfigFields.with {
            create() {
                type = "int"
                name = "VALUE"
                value = "1"
            }
        }

        android.buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
            }
        }

        android.productFlavors {
            create("flavor1") {
                applicationId = 'com.app'
            }
        }

        android.sources {
            main {
                java {
                    source {
                        srcDir 'src'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

my project structure looks like this:

```
APP
Java/
Java/android.support
Java/com.test.test_experimental
Java/com.test.test_experimental/R
Java/com.test.test_experimental
Java/com.test.test_experimentalBuildConfig
Java/com.test.test_experimental
Java/com.test.test_experimental/MainActivity
tests/
tests/com.test.test_experimental
tests/com.test.test_experimental/ApplicationTest.java
tests/com.test.test_experimental
tests/com.test.test_experimental/BuildConfig.java
resources/
test-resources
gradle/scripts/
```

I am getting these errors:

```
2:51:31 PM Gradle sync started
2:51:34 PM Gradle sync failed: Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor_Impl'.
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Error:Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor_Impl'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.


Brother:TestNative_exp blubee$ ./gradlew clean --stacktrack

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/bb/TestNative_exp/app/build.gradle' line: 10

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Exception thrown while executing model rule: model.android
   > Cannot set readonly property: minSdkVersion for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor_Impl

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug                                                                             option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.619 secs
```

**line #10 is: minSdkVersion = 10** 
You can see the whole file in the `build.gradle` that i put above.

**edit**

As @unbekant pointed out in his comment and the link to [this post](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental)

The min and target sdk values should be set like this:

```
minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
```

I tried that as well, I get this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Exception thrown while executing model rule: model.android
   > No such property: buildConfigFields for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.AndroidConfig

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug                                                                           option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to put these blocks **outside** the `android` block.

```
android.buildTypes
android.sources
android.productFlavors
```

Also the `buildConfigFields.with` should be inside the  `defaultConfig` or inside the `buildTypes` or `productFlavors`:

Something like:

```
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 22
        buildToolsVersion = "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            //----
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 10
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23

            buildConfigFields.with {
                create() {
                    //....
                }
            }
        }
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            //
        }
    }
    android.productFlavors {
       //
    }

    // Configures source set directory.
    android.sources {
        //
    }
}
```

Also, the last version is **0.2.1**.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.1'
```

Comment: Thanks! The thing that got me was the changing: minSdkVersion => minSdkVersion.apiLevel and targetSdkVersion => targetSdkVersion.apiLevel

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial? Oh, that. Where are the links?

> The current version is 0.2.0.

or dates?

I googled every one of the missing files individually (maybe 3 dozen!) after adding:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.1'
```

I tried the alpha version too but I failed finding some of its dependencies altogether.

First I get a couple of dependencies I can be bothered chasing down:

```
> Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.1.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/0.2.1/gradle-experimental-0.2.1.pom
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/0.2.1/gradle-experimental-0.2.1.jar
```

Once each of these was added to the given path seven more would sprout up in its place. If someone could post how to automatically update these (they still aren't in the latest 1.4RC1 Android Studio) it would be very useful. I got most of the stuff from maven, eg http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.lint/lint-checks/24.3.1

I got all the files to shut up Gradle's whining and you know what it said?

```
     Error:(34, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.  Consider trying the new experimental plugin.  For details, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.  Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration.
```

Which was exactly the error that led me to migrate to experimental and no better than the stock 1.3.0 that ships with AS (though it was defaulting to 1.2.3).

Why did I bother? I want to debug NDK and couldn't see what else I wasn't doing apart from not using an experimental build.

This goose chase was just a big waste of time. I'm back to using

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

No doubt I can fix it somewhere else but just a warning to others chasing experimental dependencies; they are unicorns.

Answer (score 0):

@jonagon
Some examples are in this repo:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk

probably could try:

- Use the latest plugin version. Find it at:https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental
- check https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-jni/app/build.gradle for product flavors

jni folder issue:

1. it is default for gradle experimental plugin, also for older c++ support NOT using gradle-experimental plugin ( android plugin )
2. if you have that folder and not using experimental plugin, Gradle thinks that app is using the older android studio c++ support. It gives your that warning "NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin" and recommend you to experimental plugin. it could be silenced with:

   - sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []

or just rename that jni folder to something else: it will cause more trouble if you want to android-studio cmake/ndk-build in the future, rename is better.