# android studio experimental ndk c library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I built some test c and c++ programs using gradle following [these examples](http://carlosvin.github.io/en/posts/gradle-cpp.html)

I was also able to setup android studio with the experimental features to build a android project calling native functions with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624399/android-studio-with-experimental-gradle-0-2-0/32624978#32624978)

I know that I can build this project using the `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true`

and provide my android.mk file for android studio to compile and build the app.

Is it possible with the experimental feature to build this same program? This project is built with CMAKE and there are some compilation steps that output files that needs to link. **ndk-build** creates these files but I can't find a way to do it with with android experimental features.

I am attempting for testing purposes and to build a non trivial example of building a more complex project. I decided to try to build [the zlib library](http://www.zlib.net/).

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "me.test.testnative_exp"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 10
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"

            buildConfigFields.with {
                create() {
                    type = "int"
                    name = "VALUE"
                    value = "1"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "hello-jni"
        cppFlags  += "-I${file("src/main/jni/zlib")}".toString()
        stl         = "stlport_static"
    }

    android.buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
        }
    }

    android.sources {
        main {
            java {
                source {
                    srcDir 'src'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

my project structure is

```
app/
build/
libs/
src/
src/main/testActivity.java
jni/zlib  <- the zlib folder is the one that I downloaded from the zlib website.
jni/hello-jni.c
```

After syncing the build.gradle I get a link error on the header in file:
**infbak9.c cannot find #include "zutil.h"**

but both files are in the zlib directory under jni.

Is it possible to use the android studio experimental ndk build to compile this project?

Answer (score 0):

there is good project in github that i use its structure in mine, it is nice example for start on "how use experimental(v_0.4.0) plugin in complex project?" :

https://github.com/frogermcs/FlatBuffs

*there are zlib in android NDK, just add appropriate cflag and `ldLibs.add("z")` in gradle. and in your native code `include <zlib.h>`

and a good experimental gradle config from google :
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/229cbe86238d401bb06166b8dfadec8198532589/native-codec/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

you might check this repo for a group of samples:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk

your issue might be able to fixed by adding something as[from Teapot sample there]:
cppFlags.addAll(['-I' + "${ndkDir}/sources/android/cpufeatures",'-I' + file('src/main/jni/ndk_helper')])

just replace the directory with your own path "zutil.h" etc. you may also use the latest gradle-experimental version to simplify your script -- like removing ".with" for defaultConfig.with, delete java 7 version section( the latest android studio could handle java 8 ), those ".toString()" thing is also wordy so the samples have changed style to use "+" [those is not problem for your build error though]